# What is the difference if I put Main() inside a struct instead of a class?

Tags: c#

What is the difference if I put the static method `Main()` inside a struct instead of a class?

```
struct Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

If there is no difference, why did Microsoft choose a class for its container by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference whatsoever.
(beyond the ordinary differences between structs and classes)

If you don't create any instances of the type, you should put it in a `static class`.
If you do, you should decide based on the actual usage of the type.

Comment: Why should it be in a `static class` if you don't create any instnaces of the type, instead of `struct`?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen: To prevent you from creating instances, and to document your intentions.

Answer (score 0):

### There is *NO* difference from the Application Statup Point of View.

If you look at the IL codes.

- In case of `struct` the program class extends from `System.ValueType`, while in case of `class` the program extends from `System.Object`

For `class`

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit Program
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor() cil managed
    {
        .maxstack 8
        L_0000: ldarg.0 
        L_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        L_0006: ret 
    }

    .method private hidebysig static void Main(string[] args) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack 8
        L_0000: ldstr "Hello World"
        L_0005: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        L_000a: ret 
    }

}
```

For `struct`

```
.class private sequential ansi sealed beforefieldinit Program
    extends [mscorlib]System.ValueType
{
    .method private hidebysig static void Main(string[] args) cil managed
    {
        .entrypoint
        .maxstack 8
        L_0000: ldstr "Hello World"
        L_0005: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        L_000a: ret 
    }

}
```